# Making button with SVG animation responsive

Tags: html, css, svg

I am working on a header with several buttons that include an animated hover effect. They look good when viewed at full size, but when the screen is made smaller, it completely skews and breaks the effect.

Is there a way I can get the entire div and everything within it to scale proportionally?

```css
.svg-wrapper {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  align: center;
}

#shape {
  align-content: center;
  stroke-width: 6px;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #fb9715;
  stroke-dasharray: 85 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -220;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}

#text {
  margin-top: -42px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 8pt;
}

.svg-wrapper:hover #shape {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: #fb9715;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper" style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <div align="center">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="147px">
        <rect id="shape" height="100%" width="100%" />
        <div id="text" align="center">
            <p>
          <a href=""><span class="spot">BLOG</span></a>
          </p>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your HTML has errors. Is that what you have in your environment, or an error only here on SO? You should fix those first before people can help you. (you have no closing tag on the `<svg>`)

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in your code:

Inside an svg element you can't use html tags.

For text you can use `<text>` In SVG there is an `<a>` tag - so you can use this one.

In order to center the text you can use the `text-anchor="middle"` and set the x atribute in the center.

If you want to make it responsive you need to give the svg a viewBox attribute and no width and height. This way the svg element will take all the width available.

```css
svg{width:90vh;}

#shape {
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke-dasharray: 85 400;
  stroke-dashoffset: -220;
  transition: 1s all ease;
}

#shape:hover {
  stroke-dasharray: 50 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper" style="white-space:nowrap;">
  <div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" >
        <rect id="shape" x="2" y="2" width="146" height="146" fill="none" stroke="#fb9715" stroke-width="3" />
       <a href="#" class="spot">
         <text id="text" text-anchor="middle" x="75" y="130">
          BLOG
        </text></a>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful.